# multiple inconsistent states and multiple deadlocks

Tags: database-design

Do these plural 'states' and 'deadlocks' mean that multiple inconsistent  states and multiple deadlocks may occur? If they were singular (an inconsistent state, a deadlock) then would there be only one of them at a time, please?

> If we do not use locking, or if we unlock data items too soon after
> reading or writing them, we may get inconsistent **states**. On the
> other hand, if we do not unlock a data item before requesting a lock
> on another data item, **deadlocks** may occur.

Database System Concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multiple deadlocks can occur on the same resources, depending on the complexity of the race condition occuring.

Comment: Many thanks @J.D.

Comment: @learn9909 Sure thing, np!